# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs

```
I am getting this error. I have defined all components in index.js and I am using react-dom.
```

**Webpacker** itself is compiling with no errors or warnings.

error : Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
**index.js**

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './components/CustomerSearch';


// Render the main component into the dom
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**AppComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import {Grid} from 'Adding my own package here';
import EventEmitter from 'wolfy87-eventemitter';


export default class AppComponent extends React.Component {

  emitter = null;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

    this.emitter.addListener('result', function (args) {
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Search">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column width={4}>
            <SearchForm updatechForm emitter={this.emitter}/>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={12}>
            <ResultList emitter={this.emitter}/>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppComponent.defaultProps = {};
```

**error**

```
warning.js:35 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
printWarning @ warning.js:35
warning @ warning.js:59
createElement @ ReactElementValidator.js:192
(anonymous) @ index.js:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 35891eb36bf51eb82cc9:19
module.exports @ bootstrap 35891eb36bf51eb82cc9:62
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 35891eb36bf51eb82cc9:62
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (instantiateReactComponent.js:74)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:366)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:104)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
```

Comment: It might not be related to your problem but is it necessary to export AppComponent twice ?
PS : In your **index.js** you import `{ App } from './components/CustomerSearch';` but there is no mention of AppComponent.

Comment: I am new for reactjs, I made page by help of below link
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_events.htm
Sorry, I am not sure where I am exporting twice AppComponent but my understanding says I am exporting once in customersearch.js(AppComponent.js)

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting the error as saying that maybe you forgot to export your `Grid` (or maybe your `App`) component. Is that something you have checked? (In the two files where those components are defined).

And as [abdul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3581692/abdul) said, it's possible the import is in the wrong format. It depends on whether you have exported the components by `export` or `export default`.

For components (or functions, constants etc) that are exported using just  `export` you need to import it with the syntax of `import {ComponentName} from ...`. Else, if they are exported by `export default`, then they are imported without the curly braces (`import ComponentName from ..`).

Answer (score 1):

This error is most likely caused because of your import statement. First this is weird  `import { App } from './components/CustomerSearch';` because here what i expect is that you have a file named CustomSearch.js but from your question it's AppComponent.js so i suggest you change it like this

```
import App from './components/AppComponent';
```

//here the name `App` doesn't matter as long as you're making a default export which you're doing.

Comment: @d.g `import CustomerSearch from './components/CustomerSearch.js';`
Don't wrap it with braces.

Comment: Change this `export default class CustomerSearch` to 
 `class CustomerSearch`
and at the end of your component do the export like 
`export default CustomerSearch`

Comment: @I did as well still have an error 
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `CustomerSearch`.
    in CustomerSearch
 Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in Check the render method of `CustomerSearch`.

Comment: now my CustomerSearch.js looks like 

import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'Adding my own package here';
import EventEmitter from 'wolfy87-eventemitter';
class CustomerSearch extends React.Component { .... } 
CustomerSearch.defaultProps = {};

export default CustomerSearch;