# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs

**Reactjs Context Provider Error**

I'm getting the following error

> invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Here is my `app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { UserProvider } from "./lib/user.js"

const App = () => <UserProvider></UserProvider>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

and here is the `./lib/user.js`:

```
import React from 'react'

export const UserContext = React.createContext({
  user: null,
  logIn: ((token, user) => {}),
  logOut: (() => {})
})

export class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.logIn = (token, user) => {
      setToken(token)
      this.setState(state => ({user: user}))
    }

    this.logOut = (client) => {
      clearToken()
      this.setState(state => ({user: null}))
      client.resetStore()
      client.cache.reset()
    }

    this.state = {
      user: null,
      logIn: this.logIn,
      logOut: this.logOut
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(<div></div>)
    console.log(<UserContext.Provider/>)
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <p>hi</p>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

This is on React 16.3.2.  There are many situations where the error is due to default vs named exports, which this is not appear to be:

1. [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)
2. [Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842373/uncaught-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-compone)
3. [Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897070/element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-class)

Comment: Works fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn7no02225 Can you edit (the dependencies, maybe?) so it reproduces your error?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using `react@16.3` with an earlier `react-dom` version (e.g. 16.2) that doesn't support context yet.

Comment: Thanks @DanAbramov!  I was using `react-dom` 16.2 and hadn't upgraded it.