# react-slick - Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm trying to create a simple slider yet when I `map` the data, as opposed to simply adding html in to the slider, I get the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

const WishAddImage = () => {
    const imgArray = [
        {
            src: 'https://www.reiss.com/media/product/653/024/20-1.jpg?format=jpeg&auto=webp&quality=85&width=250&height=287&fit=bounds'
        },
        {
            src: 'https://www.reiss.com/media/product/993/016/76-1.jpg?format=jpeg&auto=webp&quality=85&width=250&height=287&fit=bounds'
        }
    ];

    const sliderSettings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    const wishImage = <Slider {...sliderSettings}>{imgArray.map(img => `<div><img src='${img.src}' /></div>`)}</Slider>;

    // const wishImage = ( /* <-- this works as it should when html used */
    //     <Slider {...sliderSettings}>
    //         <div>
    //             <h1>1</h1>
    //         </div>
    //         <div>
    //             <h1>2</h1>
    //         </div>
    //     </Slider>
    // );
    return <div>{wishImage}</div>;
};

export default WishAddImage;
```

I have seen these similar questions, which do not apply to me:

1. [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)
2. [Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842373/uncaught-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-compone)
3. [Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897070/element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-class)

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

I'm using react & react-dom v 16.6.3

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link to reproduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your quotes characters in:

```
 const wishImage = <Slider {...sliderSettings}>{imgArray.map(img => <div><img src={img.src} /></div>)}</Slider>;
```